# Marketing Cloud bounces included in open rate?

Tags: marketing-cloud, bounce-management

I am new to Marketing Cloud and was wondering if hard/soft bounces are included in the open rate percentage when sending an email through marketing cloud? Or does the system only consider emails that were successfully delivered for its calculation of the open rate?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Remember to mark my answer as accepted if it has been helpful

Answer (score 1):

The answer is simple: No.

Hard and soft bounces are not counted toward the open rate because, as you've said, the email is not delivered, hence, the tracking pixel (1x1 pixel transparent GIF image) is not shown.

Comment: I think OP is more about asking if open rates are calculated as percentage of emails sent or emails delivered. So if you send 100 emails and 10 are bounced, will 20 opens be equal to 20% open rate, or 22% open rate.

Answer (score 1):

[This article](https://www.salesforce.com/ca/blog/2020/09/know-your-metric--email-marketing-open-rates.html) explains it quite well:

> Open rate = Emails opened / (emails sent - bounces)

So, let's look at a specific example. If you send 100 emails, 10 are bounced and 20 opened, the open rate would be 20% if you only calculate it based on sends. But the correct open rate, and the open rate actually used in SFMC will be 22%, as you calculate it based on emails actually received.

Comment: Thank you, Lukas! The example and the article makes it good to understand.

Comment: @user140863 - don't forget to mark my answer as accepted, if it has been helpful